# How can I use just Roboto font with SVG's?

Tags: fonts, svg

I am using Adobe Illustator to make some SVGs.  I need the font-family to be ONLY **roboto** for the web. However every time I save it shows other roboto fonts like **Roboto-Regular** and **Roboto-Light**.  I tried installing the roboto web font from google fonts and restarted illustrator.

Here is an example of code:

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 977.2227 293.7242)" display="inline" fill="#B3B3B3" 
font-family="'Roboto-Regular'" font-size="19.1122">SVG</text>

<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 977.2227 339.6242)" display="inline" fill="#099AE2"     
font-family="'Roboto-Light'" font-size="20.2365">Test</text>
```

The simple solution is to just find and replace in my text editor however as I am going to be doing this in a lot in the future I would like to figure out the cause/real solution to make it just roboto.

I have been searching for answers all day and haven't been successful.  I am sure this is simple and any step in the right direction is very much appreciated.

Font URL on website is:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A400%2C300%2C100%2C500%2C700%2C500italic%2C400italic%2C300italic%2C100italic%2C700italic

Comment: I think Illustrator wouldn't be able to do this and using the text editor is a good idea. If you use multiple weights you maybe should add them in manually, too. Like: Find: font-family="Roboto-Light" -> Replace: font-family="Roboto" font-weight="300" .  I tend to write me little scripts to automate Find/Replace tasks for multiple strings.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry, You are already using correct font. `Roboto-regular` is the main font in `Roboto family` often called as just `Roboto`.

Comment: Roboto-regular won't show properly in web.  The URL I am loading for the font is https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A400%2C300%2C100%2C500%2C700%2C500italic%2C400italic%2C300italic%2C100italic%2C700italic .

Comment: @Jessica there is a little problem in your code, try to delete double quotes where you specified your font name e.g  **font-family="'Roboto-Regular'"** change it as **font-family="Roboto-Regular"**.

Comment: Hi,  I think you meant single quotes and that does not fix the issue.  All though your mention is correct HTML syntax both will render just fine.  The font-family has to only be font-family="roboto"  .  font-family="Roboto-Regular" won't work.  I need to be able to save just as roboto in Illustrator.

Comment: This is incorrect. `Roboto-regular` is not a functioning font family name for the Google font. It is the name of a particular face, not the family, and specifying it as the family name will not work.